# Segmentation fault when trying to clean object in Gtest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

So, this is my test. But it has segmentation fault on the last line: m->service-> clean. And if I don't use this function, I have memory leaks. Is there any alternative?

```
class ServiceTest: public ::testing::Test
{
    protected:
    virtual void    SetUp()
    {
        m_service = new conn::tsm::Service();
    }

    virtual void    TearDown()
    {
        delete m_service;
        m_service = 0;
    }

    // Tested Object:
    conn::Service     *m_service;
};

TEST_F(ServiceTest, CatchChildDelete)
{
    conn::IObject_mock *testParam = new conn::IObject_mock();

    m_service->setId(0x01);
    EXPECT_CALL(*testParam, getId()).WillRepeatedly(::testing::Return(0x01));

    EXPECT_TRUE(m_service->addObject(testParam));

    EXPECT_CALL(*testParam, die()).WillOnce(::testing::Throw(std::exception()));

    m_service->clean();
}
```

And this is the implementation of clean():

```
void Service::clean() throw()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<IObject *>::iterator it = m_objectTable.end();
        for( it = m_objectTable.begin(); it != m_objectTable.end();++it )
        {
            delete (*it);
        }

        /* clear cache */
        m_objectMap.clear();
        m_objectTable.clear();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Keywords: [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), [The rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: if `die` is called from within destructor of IObject - then it is not virtual call. Anyway provide definition of IObject and IObject_mock,